# Transferring data between DE 1 and DE 2 when record not present in DE 3

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, sqlserver

I have 3 data extensions: Master, Local and additional, supporting one which essentially functions as historical Storage of all the records that ever landed in Local. So the data flows like this Master > Local > Storage

Now, I want to have a query which will transfer data from Master to Local but only if such record doesn't already exist in Record Storage. I am using overwrite function as neither Local nor Storage have a Primary Key.

To determine whether a record exists in Storage I check two different fields and only if such combination doesn't already exist in Storage, I move the record to Local.

Everything works as intended until the moment when in Storage appears a record where one of these two fields is empty. From that point on the query below doesn't work anymore and always brings 0 records from Master to Local.  Any idea how to get rid of the problem?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [Master]
WHERE
([Task:Description] +''+ [Task:What:Case:Id]) NOT IN (SELECT ([Task:Description] +''+ [Task:What:Case:Id]) FROM [Storage])
```

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working. A NOT IN query will not return any rows if any NULLs exists in the list of NOT IN values.

Comment: yup, adding IS NOT NULL seem to solve the problem. This is the updated query:  `SELECT 
    *
FROM
    [Master]
WHERE
([Task:Description] +''+ [Task:What:Case:Id]) NOT IN (SELECT ([Task:Description] +''+ [Task:What:Case:Id]) FROM [Storage] WHERE [Task:Description] IS NOT NULL )   `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather T-SQL question. A **NOT IN** query will not return any rows if any NULLs exists in the list of NOT IN values. Add **IS NOT NULL** in the sub-query Where clause. This will filter out all rows whith NULLs and, hence, the **IN** statement will work as you expect.

Check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231712/sql-not-in-not-working) .

Comment: Please summarize what you found instead of just linking to another post.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs thank you for your review. Actually that was my point **A NOT IN query will not return any rows if any NULLs exists in the list of NOT IN values.** I put a link because I found the answer there. I will update the post anyway.